# How to access values inside a map from a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, key-value

I have a java class which adds keys and values to a map, which works fine. I need to access these values in a JSP page

During debugging this is the structure of the map:

```
 riskIdx.month={Feb=40, Mar=50, Apr=10, May=20, Jan=30}
```

This is how I am trying to access the values of the map in the JSP page:

```
 chart(${riskIdx.Jan},${riskIdx.Feb},${riskIdx.Mar},${riskIdx.Apr},${riskIdx.May})
```

This doesnt work. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: What is chart here? Is it a method? We need to see more code.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal chart is a method in another JSP page which is used to draw a chart. It works fine. If i pass in values such as chart(10,20,31,45) the chart is drawn. I have trouble accessing the map and passing them into the chart method.

Comment: No, I meant I need to see the scriptlet (<% %> if you're using them) to invoke the chart from JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mainPageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MainPageBean implements Serializable {
  private Map<String, Boolean> isUserInRole = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
  ....
```

In *.xhtml:

```
  ... disabled="#{!(mainPageBean.isUserInRole['ROLE'])}"
```